# How to reload the background image from css in php?

Tags: php, html, css, browser, reload

I use a separated `CSS` to load a background image from my local file. A tedious thing is `PHP` does not update its cache after I modified the file. For me, giving a random number to the background URL also was not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1 width=device-width">
    <title>PHP-001</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      test
    </section>
  </body>
</html>

section {
  background: url("./public/images/bg1.jpg?v=002");
}
```

So I gave the `<style>` element directly to the `<head>` element for force updating the `PHP`. This one basically works, but it does not save the image permanently to the browser file. After I remove the `<style>` parts then try to load the image from the `CSS`, it doesn't work again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1 width=device-width">
    <title>PHP-001</title>
    <style media="screen">
      header {
        background: url("./public/images/section.png?v=<?php echo time(); ?>");
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      test
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J59RY.png)

I want to load/reload my background image from the `CSS` file.

Any tips to resolve the problem?

Comment: None of this appears to have anything to do with PHP, or at least it's not obvious why it would. What exactly do you mean by `A tedious thing is PHP does not update its cache after I modified the file`? Instead of giving us your speculations as to the cause of the problem (without any clear evidence presented), it would be much more useful to tell us what actual behaviour are you seeing and why that is causing you a problem. FWIW PHP doesn't cache your CSS files. But the webserver might. Or the browser might. Or are you saying there's an issue with the time() function? It's all a bit unclear.

Comment: As ADyson said, this is not PHP at all. CSS files are static content, and are served with long-lived caching headers by default by all HTTP servers. The files are then cached accordingly such by client browers and intermediate caches, eg: CDNs, proxies, etc. It's all working as intended, except that you're changing the file's contents without changing the filename. You can add trash to the URL and break the caching that way, as others have suggested, but the root cause is that you're not changing the filename when the content changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, just to note that PHP is not doing any cacheing. As @ADyson has pointed out in a comment, your server or your browser might cache things.

The problem you have expressed seems to be that 'somewhere' the background image is being cached and not being refreshed when you change the image as the url stays the same.

You have tried:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

but all that does is make the browser (or whoever) think it had better reload the styles.css and not use a cached version (if it has one). So it doesn't work to refresh the image as you have observed.

But, when you tried

```
<style media="screen">
  header {
    background: url("./public/images/section.png?v=<?php echo time(); ?>");
  }
</style>
```

You did get the new image.

In the first case, loading from the css file, no one has told the browser (or whoever) that it should not use the image it has already cached if it has one. It looks at the url and finds it's the same as one it already has so doesn't bother getting it again.

One way is to carry on as you did in the second case as that works. Or get the CSS file rewritten with something random like your ?v=something

Comment: This will invalidate the cache on every single request, which is not exactly ideal. Either change your web server's settings regarding the cache headers it sets for static files [which is usually "forever", because static files are static] or do the proper thing and name your static files according to their content so that the cache behaviour is irrelevant.